# Does Draconic Breath qualify for Metabreath Feats?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, sorcerer

I stumbled upon an interesting feat called *Draconic Breath* in the Complete Arcane and decided to read up on it. It reads as follows:

> [Draconic]
>
> You can convert your arcane spells into a breath weapon.
>
> Prerequisite:
> Draconic Heritage
>
> Benefit
>
> As a standard action, you can change arcane spell energy into a breath weapon of your draconic heritage energy type. The breath weapon is a 30-foot cone (fire or cold) or a 60-foot line (acid or electricity) that deals 2d6 points of damage per level of the spell that you expended to create the effect. Any creature in the area can make a Reflex save (DC 10 + level of the spell used + your Cha modifier) for half damage. This is a supernatural ability.

There are plenty of spells available, which empower breath weapons that are not racial or class features such as *Stunning Breath* applying specifically to the *Dragon Breath* spell. However, I wonder if a PC, simply by virtue of having the feat above, qualifies for Metabreath feats (which is apparently not the case, according to a thread on the Draginfire Adepts's breath weapon in a similar context), and/or feats that apply to supernatural abilities such as *Widen Supernatural Ability*, since the feat in itself does not grant a supernatural ability. Or does it?

Comment: The most recent version of the feat Draconic Breath appears in *Races of the Dragon* on page 102. If being all official-like, that's the one that should be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The feat Draconic Breath doesn't meet the metabreath feats' type requirements

The feat Draconic Breath (*Races of the Dragon* 102) doesn't grant a breath weapon "whose time between breaths is expressed in rounds" (*Draconomicon* 66). The feat Draconic Breath's breath weapon can't be affected by metabreath feats.

#### The feat Draconic Breath grants a supernatural ability; feats that apply to supernatural abilities can be used with it...

Thus a character could pick the feats Empower Supernatural Ability (*Tome of Magic* 74), Enlarge Supernatural Ability (*Tome of Magic* 73), and Widen Supernatural Ability (*Tome of Magic* 75) and apply their effects to the feat Draconic Breath's breath weapon. (The feat Extend Supernatural Ability (*Tome of Magic* 73-4) won't do anything.) No further metamagical supernatural ability feats were officially published.

#### ...And so can breath channeling feats

Breath channeling feats (*Races of the Dragon* 101) don't have the restrictions that metabreath feats have, requiring only a breath weapon. Use those with the feat Draconic Breath's breath weapon; I recommend the feat Entangling Exhalation (*Races of the Dragon* 101).